# How to open multiple hrefs within a webtable to scrape through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape this website using python and selenium. However all the information I need is not on the main page, so how would I click the links in the 'Application number' column one by one go to that page scrape the information then return to original page?

Ive tried:

```
def getData():
  data = []
  select = Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="node-41"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/@href'))
  list_options = select.options
  for item in range(len(list_options)):
    item.click()
  driver.get(url)
```

URL: http://www.scilly.gov.uk/planning-development/planning-applications

Screenshot of the site:
[image]

Comment: does it open the link in new tab or same window? Also, show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: no it doesnt open a new tab it opens it on the same window and ive edited to show what I tried

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open multiple hrefs within a webtable to scrape through selenium you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    hrefs = []
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('http://www.scilly.gov.uk/planning-development/planning-applications')
    windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle # Store the parent_window_handle for future use
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.views-field.views-field-title>a"))) # Induce WebDriverWait for the visibility of the desired elements
    for element in elements:
        hrefs.append(element.get_attribute("href")) # Collect the required href attributes and store in a list
    for href in hrefs:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('" + href +"');") # Open the hrefs one by one through execute_script method in a new tab
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) # Induce  WebDriverWait for the number_of_windows_to_be 2
        windows_after = driver.window_handles
        new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0] # Identify the newly opened window
        # driver.switch_to_window(new_window) <!---deprecated>
        driver.switch_to.window(new_window) # switch_to the new window
        # perform your webscraping here
        print(driver.title) # print the page title or your perform your webscraping
        driver.close() # close the window
        # driver.switch_to_window(windows_before) <!---deprecated>
        driver.switch_to.window(windows_before) # switch_to the parent_window_handle
    driver.quit() #Quit your program
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
    Planning application: P/18/064 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/063 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/062 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/061 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: p/18/059 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/058 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/057 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/056 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/055 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
    Planning application: P/18/054 | Council of the ISLES OF SCILLY
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [WebScraping JavaScript-Rendered Content using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144599/webscraping-javascript-rendered-content-using-selenium-in-python/59156403#59156403)
- [StaleElementReferenceException even after adding the wait while collecting the data from the wikipedia using web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623799/staleelementreferenceexception-even-after-adding-the-wait-while-collecting-the-d/65631425#65631425)
- [Unable to access the remaining elements by xpaths in a loop after accessing the first element- Webscraping Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706039/unable-to-access-the-remaining-elements-by-xpaths-in-a-loop-after-accessing-the/59712944#59712944)
- [How to open each product within a website in a new tab for scraping using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640584/how-to-open-each-product-within-a-website-in-a-new-tab-for-scraping-using-seleni/57641549#57641549)
- [How to open multiple hrefs within a webtable to scrape through selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277877/how-to-open-multiple-hrefs-within-a-webtable-to-scrape-through-selenium/52281843#52281843)

Comment: it works thank you but if you can comments would help understand the code even more?

Comment: @LibanWest Updated the solution with required comments for your convenience

Comment: hello if your available and free I have question I could use your help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364188/handle-pagination-with-input-buttons-in-selenium

Comment: Oh Im sorry I thought i did but it looks like i just accepted :) fixed it

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import Webdriver
import time

url = "url"
browser = Webdriver.Chrome() #or whatever driver you use
browser.find_element_by_class_name("views-field views-field-title").click()
# or use this browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
#Note you will need to change the class name to click a different item in the table
    time.sleep(5) # not the best way to do this but its simple. Just to make sure things load
#it is here that you will be able to scrape the new url I will not post that as you can scrape what you want. 
# When you are done scraping you can return to the previous page with this
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: <=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to new page DOM is refreshed and you cannot use list method here. Here is my approach for this action (I don't code much in python so syntax and indendation may be broken)

```
count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='views-table cols-6']/tbody/tr") # to count total number of links
len(count)
j = 1
if j<=len:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='views-table cols-6']/tbody/tr["+str(j)+"]/td/a").click()

    #add wait here
    #do your scrape action here  

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Back to planning applications']").click()#to go back to main page

    #add wait here for main page to load.
    j+=1
```

Comment: and  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='views-table cols-6']/tbody/tr["+j+"]/td/a").click()
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: try again now with updated code. I have added str to j. Note the change here str(j)