# Why is switch_to_window() method not working for selenium webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webautomation

I am trying to switch to a newly opened window using the Python selenium webdriver. The code worked fine before but now it is showing error. Surprisingly, the switch_to_window() method is not being recognized by Python and has no declaration to go to.

```
def process_ebl_statements(self, account_number):

    current_window = self.driver.current_window_handle
    all_windows = self.driver.window_handles

    print("Current window: ", current_window)
    print("All windows: ", all_windows)
    number_of_windows = len(all_windows)
    self.driver.switch_to_window(all_windows[number_of_windows - 1])
```

Error details:

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to_window'
```

[image]

Comment: What changes occurred between the `The code worked fine before` and `but now it is showing error` ?

Comment: Also driver.switch_to_window is depreciated use driver.switch_to.window

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567464/how-to-switch-window-handles-using-selenium-and-python also to use a new window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message...

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to_window'
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) object no more supports the attribute *switch_to_window()*

---

### switch_to_window

[switch_to_window](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f7a4c21aceb1368f602cfcc9a342788442d483bb/py/CHANGES#L688) was deprecated in [Selenium v2.41](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f7a4c21aceb1368f602cfcc9a342788442d483bb/py/CHANGES#L686) :

> Selenium 2.41
>
> - deprecating switch_to_* in favour of driver.switch_to.*

Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

Instead of `switch_to_window` you need to use [switch_to](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to).

Examples:

- *`driver.switch_to.active_element`*
- *`driver.switch_to.alert`*
- *`driver.switch_to.default_content()`*
- *`driver.switch_to.frame()`*
- *`driver.switch_to.parent_frame()`*
- *`driver.switch_to.window('main')`*