# Is it possible for selenium to have all the browser tabs focused simultaneously?

Tags: python, selenium

My project needs to have about 5 or 6 active tabs in each browser instance, is it possible for selenium to have each tab of a browser focused at the same time so, for example, video autoplay can continue to work on all tabs simultaneously?

I'm aware of `driver.switchTo().window();` but that will just change the focus to another tab while I need something that will keep all active tabs in focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***No***, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) can [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) at only one tab at a time.

To switch focus to other [tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893230/7429447) you would need to do [*window handling*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360579/7429447).