# Data reset on Selenium tab change

Tags: python, selenium, focus, window-handles

While trying to use the data I get from one tab in the other tab with selenium, it resets the data when the tab changes, so I can't use the data. How can I prevent this?

My Code :

```
for link in linkler:
driver.get(link)
oyunAdi = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']").text
oyunFiyat = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='table-prices-current']//td[3]").text
try:
    community = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='tab-communityitems']").click()
    sleep(1)
    isimler = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='item-class-2']//div//div[@class='community-item']")
    devam = "a"
except:
    devam = "b"
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    a = 0
if devam == "a":
    for isim in isimler:
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        sleep(0.5)
        arama = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='findItemsSearchBox']")
        arama.clear()
        arama.send_keys(oyunAdi, isim.text)
        sleep(3)
        esyaIsimler = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='market_listing_item_name']")
        fiyatlar = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='normal_price']")
        for x in range(0,len(esyaIsimler)):
            if esyaIsimler[x].text == isim:
                print(oyunAdi, oyunFiyat, esyaIsimler[x].text, fiyatlar[x].text)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

For example, the output of the code below is 10.

```
isimler = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='item-class-2']//div//div[@class='community-item']")
print(len(isimler))
```

but this code gives error

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(len(isimler))
```

I want to use the data of the `isimler` variable that I got from the previous tab in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

The elements within the list ***isimler*** is from the *parent tab* and are associated with the [parent window_handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs/53692407#53692407).

As you [switch window_handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230) using `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])` and focus to the [adjascent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567464/how-to-switch-window-handles-using-selenium-and-python/57568925#57568925) Selenium looses [**focus**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518772/how-to-focus-object-in-selenium-web-driver/59521886#59521886) on the [parent window_handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click/47089023#47089023).

As *Selenium* doesn't have focus on the parent tab, hence `print(len(isimler))` shows error.

Comment: I'm already aware of this, if possible, I want not to loose the variable after the focus is gone

Comment: @EmreOz How can you even think about looking for elements of one [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) within a all together different [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)?